# Debian container unable to start after migration from OpenVZ to LXC on Proxmox 4

Tags: debian, openvz, lxc, proxmox

After migrating a Debian 7 OpenVZ CT from Proxmox 3 to a LXC on Proxmox 4 it does not appear to start correctly. Fristly, migration was done by stopping the container on Proxmox 3, backing up to external harddisk, then loading that harddisk in Proxmox 4, restoring that backup and setting the network config. After that, the container appears to start correctly according to Proxmox but is a not able to be connected to through either console (tty), gives a blank output, no login or whatsoever, or SSH (connection refused). Restarting both the CT and host does not seem to have any effect, and starting the CT with the `lxc-start -n 101` with a  `-o` log file gives the following output:

```
lxc-start 1445190074.912 ERROR    lxc_commands - commands.c:lxc_cmd_rsp_send:237 - failed to send command response -1 Broken pipe
lxc-start 1445190074.913 ERROR    lxc_commands - commands.c:lxc_cmd_rsp_send:237 - failed to send command response -1 Broken pipe
```

Any ideas on how to diagnose where this problem may be coming from or how to go about fixing it?

EDIT: All other containers migrated the exact same way worked perfectly out of the box...

EDIT 2: One thing that may be interesting to point out, I seem to be getting a lot of these errors when looking at the boot log (dmesg) of the LXC:

```
[ 9741.362095] audit: type=1400 audit(1445199000.045:102): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mount" info="failed flags match" error=-13 profile="lxc-container-default" name="/" pid=10171 comm="mount" flags="rw, remount"
```

For a more detailed bootlog of the LXC, see http://pastebin.com/2H0iAJPn